# Template tag created using JS doesn't appear when appended to shadow inside web component

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, html5-template

I would expect the following code to create an element which contains a `div` with the text "Hi" in it.

The element appears in the inspector, but no text is visible on the screen.

When I change the template from a `template` to a `div` the text shows up. What have I done wrong here?

```
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()

        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
        const template = document.createElement('template')
        const div = document.createElement('div')

        div.innerHTML = 'Hi'
        template.appendChild(div)

        shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content)
    }
}
customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<template>` is a special element.

Append some HTML elements through its `content` property:

```
template.content.appendChild(div)
```

or add the HTML code via its `innerHTML` property:

```
template.innerHTML = '<div>Hi</div>'
```

Comment: Using a `fragment` would be another solution.

Comment: Yes. And actually `content` is a DocumentFragment

Comment: Part 2 of the question. Why is it that I am unable to update a reference to template.content?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-haybrb

Comment: @DavidAlsh sorry I don't understand your question. In the link your provided you use this.content which has non sens becase `this` is not a template but the custom element itself

Comment: You should write: this.shadowRoot.appendChild(div) instead in render()

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Supersharp's answer. Here is an alternate solution without the need of `<template>`.

```js
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        const div = document.createElement('div')
        div.innerHTML = 'Hi'
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).appendChild(div)
    }
}
customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent)
```

```html
<my-component></my-component>
```

Or you can do it by just using `innerHTML` of the shadowRoot:

```js
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).innerHTML = "<div>Hi</div>";
    }
}
customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent)
```

```html
<my-component></my-component>
```